# Does AWS Aurora MySQL Load Balance Reads Across Availability Zones?

Tags: mysql, aws, aws-aurora

I am running an AWS Aurora MySQL multi-AZ cluster with four nodes in two availability zone reader A and writer C are in one AZ, and reader B and D are in another AZ.  It seems like reader A is experiencing most of the CPU load (close to 90%) during peak hours (C tends to hover around 36%) while the nodes B and D, which do not share an AZ with the writer, barely  reach 25%, despite A having double the instance CPUs.

My question is: Does the Aurora load balancer consider all nodes in the cluster when directing read traffic, even if they are in different availability zones.  The AWS image illustrating how Aurora works shows writing across AZs but reading only within AZs from the data copies (this makes sense for latency reasons), and I know there are fees incurred for data transfers across AZs for EC2s. Are applications on EC2 instances in one availability zone only able to query read instances in the same availability zone? Or does the load get distributed round-robin regardless of which AZ the aurora node is in?